# What's wrong with groovy math?

Tags: math, object, groovy

This seems quite bizarre to me and totally putting me on the side of people willing to use plain java. While writing a groovy based app I encountered such thing:

```
int filesDaily1 = (item.filesDaily ==~ /^[0-9]+$/) ?
            Integer.parseInt(item.filesDaily) : item.filesDaily.substring(0, item.filesDaily.indexOf('.'))

        def filesDaily = (item.filesDaily ==~ /^[0-9]+$/) ?
            Integer.parseInt(item.filesDaily) : item.filesDaily.substring(0, item.filesDaily.indexOf('.'))
```

So, knowing that item.filesDaily is a String with value '1..*' how can it possibly be, that filesDaily1 is equal to 49 and filesDaily is equal to 1?

What's more is that when trying to do something like

```
int numOfExpectedEntries = filesDaily * item.daysToCheck
```

an exception is thrown saying that

```
Cannot cast object '111' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'int'
```

pointing to that exact line of code with multiplication. How can that happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're assigning this value to an int:

```
item.filesDaily.substring(0, item.filesDaily.indexOf('.'))
```

I'm *guessing* that Groovy is converting the single-character string "1" into the char '1' and then taking the Unicode value in the normal char-to-int conversion... so you end up with the value 49.

If you want to parse a string as a decimal number, use `Integer.parseInt` instead of a built-in conversion.

The difference between `filesDaily1` and `filesDaily` here is that you've told Groovy that `filesDaily1` is meant to be an int, so it's applying a conversion to int. I suspect that `filesDaily` is actually the string "1" in your test case.

I *suspect* you really just want to change the code to something like:

```
String text = (item.filesDaily ==~ /^[0-9]+$/) ? items.filesDaily :
                   item.filesDaily.substring(0, item.filesDaily.indexOf('.'))
Integer filesDaily = text.toInteger()
```

Comment: +1 It's apparently one of the things being looked at for removal in Groovy 2.0 as it's confusing...  Single char strings are converted to `int` via `char`...  Multi char strings throw an exception

Comment: Yeah... noticed it few seconds after the post. Though exception message is still vague.

Comment: @den, think you can change the ternary expression into `int filesDaily1 = Integer.parseInt( ( item.filesDaily =~ /^([0-9]+).*$/ )[0][1] )` which *might* be simpler...  or not ;-)

Comment: @tim_yates, really nice one, probably not as readable, but cool!

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in the groovy type conversion code.

```
int a = '1'
int b = '11'
```

return different results because different converters are used. In the example `a` will be 49 while `b` will be 11. Why?

The single-character-to-int conversion (using `String.charAt(0)`) has a higher precedence than the integer parser.

The bad news is that this happens for all single character strings. You can even do `int a = 'A'` which gives you 65.

As long as you have no way of knowing how long the string is, you must use `Integer.parseInt()` instead of relying on the automatic type conversion.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, it's a suprising feature ;-)